# Is admin website a good candidate to use event sourcing?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am thinking of refactoring my admin website for golf databases, which currently uses the traditional CRUD architecture.

Is CQRS/Event Sourcing a good model for admin-type websites? It doesn't generate many interesting events, at most it will probably just have CourseCreated, CourseUpdated, and CourseDeleted events.

Most CQRS/Event tutorials/examples that I have seen seems to be more suitable for consumer type websites like Online Shopping cart, Ticket booking system, Restaurant order system, etc.

For Admin-type websites, are we just better off with CRUD, or does CQRS/ES have more to offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of the events you can think of contain the words Created, Updated, or Deleted then you probably don't need event sourcing.  ES is not meant to be a substitute for a CRUD site.